# My Dracaena Fragrans Is Never Happy

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

**2/15, I did this:**

I finally built up the nerve to chop my corn plant and propagate it

Here's the damage:

[image]

I am praying I did this right. I followed a video that showed how one guy did it successfully, and I'm hoping it will go that well for me. I dabbed root hormone on the bottom of the cut-off stalks and placed two in dirt, and the rest are in water (so the root hormone probably doesn't matter, but still). I am hoping at least one of these methods works!

The first pic is the original plant, which I hate to see all cut, but I am hoping it's ok.

Is it in the right light? I am trying to find the best spots for them, whether that be indoor or outdoors I don't know yet. The temperature, as far as I know, is ok.

**2/23 UPDATE**

The original stalk + a cutting is starting to yellow...

It might be sun-scorched...I moved it inside for that reason and humidity. Should I spray it with a mister for humidity?

I am so worried...I think I may be overwatering...I will definitely stop & I also will use bottled water in case it's a fluoride issue.

Here's a leaf I pulled off:

[image]

The other stalk I moved seems fine, but it's also titled as hell. I am so scared I killed it by propagating/cutting it...Help!

**3/3 UPDATE**

Oh god now it looks burned and yellow in a different way, what's happening?! I can never seem to make it happy. I am moving it to a shadier spot, and I will try and mist it. I stopped watering for a week because I thought I overwatered, but now it looks worse? HELP. Also yes it's a shady spot the exposure on the pictures are just wack.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The information given in your question is not entirely clear, but hopefully  I've interpreted it more or less correctly.

Your plant appears to be Dracaena deremensis 'Warneckii'; it does not appreciate direct sunlight, but this particular variety likes to be in medium to bright indirect light, in temperatures of around 70 deg F, though they will just about tolerate down to 50 deg F. It likes high humidity and whilst it needs regular water, overwatering may cause rot. If your plant pot is standing in an outer tray or pot, that should be emptied out 30 minutes after watering so it's not left sitting in water. If the air in your home is quite dry and hot, then standing the pot on top of pebbles in a large tray kept half topped up with water will increase the humidity around the plant, but the pot should not be in contact with the water in the tray. Otherwise, mist regularly; note these plants do not like fluoridated water.

If you have pushed stems you've cut into separate pots in an attempt to propagate, they usually root fairly easily - the cuttings should not be overwatered, nor allowed to dry out completely, try to keep the soil just about moist. Keep in the same conditions as mentioned previously, and don't panic - they'll either grow or they won't, but moving them around and trying different things frequently won't be doing them any good, just find a suitable  spot for them in your home. Do not fertilize until you see some growth starting. For the ones in water, in my experience they will (hopefully) produce roots, although I recall it  took  quite a considerable number of  weeks, such that I almost gave up - when roots appear, pot the cuttings up carefully. Further info https://www.thespruce.com/grow-d-deremensis-at-home-1902752

In respect of the first photo showing the main plant, new growth should appear from the top of the cut stems; if you would prefer growth to start lower down, cut the stems down lower now. If the foliage on the taller part starts to look even worse than it does now, you can always just cut it down to about 6 inches - so long as the main stem is not yellow or soggy, it will regrow, though it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my memory ,my present dracaena is very roughly about the 12 th  cutting of a stalk I bought in 1964. They are very forgiving. As luck would have it ,it is time to come in for winter and it is 8 ft. tall so cutting number 13 ? coming up.